# Loop Files, Get Next Number

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, script, gnome-terminal

In a directory I have the following files:

```
    000 - text.txt
    000 - info.txt
    001 - first.txt
    002 - second.txt
    aaa - more.txt
    ZZZ - text.txt
    ZZZ - info.txt
```

In Bash, how would I get the next numerical number (ie. 003)?

I want to ignore "aaa - *", "aab - *", "ZZZ - *" etc.

Currently, I am looping through all the files and using `\d\d\d`  on all files to match the highest number

pseudocode:

```
min = 000

for each file in directory
    if match \d\d\d > min
        max = match \d\d\d

printf %03d $((max + 1))
```

I'm sure there is a more efficient method (eg. maybe using ls or similar).

Comment: I'm not sure it's more efficient, though it's arguably neater, to use `ls [0-9][0-9][0-9]*.txt|tail -n 1`, then increment the number in the returned file.

Comment: careful with the regexs.  assuming no whitespace before the number in the filename, you'd want `^\d\d\d` to avoid matching a file like `zzz - foo 111 bar.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
# loop over files that start with 3 digits
# the shell will naturally order them, the last will be the max
for last in [0-9][0-9][0-9]*; do :; done

# strip the first space and everything after it
num=${last%% *}

# get the next number
((next = num + 1))

# pad with zeros
printf "%03d" $next
```